# Reduce Time for Checking Out Code in Visual Studio Online

Tags: github, azure-devops

I'm trying out VSO and it's taking over 2 minutes to sync with a GitHub repository.  It appears that it's checking out the whole thing on every build.  I made sure that the "clean" box is unchecked but it had no effect.

Any ideas on how to get it to cache the source or is this even possible in VSO?

Answer (score 0):

Each build in VSO uses a new VM that is spun up just for your build. Short 
of hosting your own Build Server connected your VSO, I don't think it can be avoided.

Unless there are ways to speed up a the process of downloading the code from a git repo, I think you're stuck.